# highlight rows in a spreadsheet that have a certian number of matched column values

Tags: excel, vba, helper

I am currently struggling to gain traction on this problem. The goal that I am trying to accomplish is to some how group rows that are most alike together. The setup: all rows are independent of one another but they can have any number of column values in that same row (up to 10). I am looking for a solution to help me find the rows that have 3 or more common values across the 10 columns and highlight them accordingly. I am just now getting into excel VBA and I have the feeling that is the direction I need to head in. I will provide a simplified set of data that I would like to do this for. In the picture, the goal I am trying to achieve is "group" rows 8 and 10 together because they have 3 or more column matches. Any help would be much appreciated!

update: I am unable to provide the data that I am actually going to use this for, but the script needs to be able to handle alpha-numeric values (ex: MELP7899797). THANK YOU FOR THE HELP SO FAR!!!!

[image]

Comment: Hello MCTP17. You could make two arrays. The first could contain the sum of all elements of the subsets of column values where the number of elements is equal or larger than 3, e.g. for first row: 1+84+5+28, 1+84+5, 1+84+28,1+5+28,84+5+28.The other array would contain the products instead of sums, e.g. 1*84*5*28, 1*84*5 etc. You could then search for duplicate values in both arrays and find matching rows. This works for many cases, but not all ( e.g. any zero: 0 1 7 7 and 0 8 6 1 )

Comment: you closed this post very soon , I  wrote the code for solve your question, anyway you can use combine the formulas `SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(range1,range2))` in your vba, and then check top rows of each row that contains matches, that will be helpfull. and you can use Function() instead of Sub() two find matches dinamically().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. Note that you must set the constant `TopLeftCell` at the top to tell the macro where your data are. In your sample the top left cell is A1. I tested with a blank row above the data so that the top-left was in A2.

```
Sub MarkMatches()
    ' 033

    Const TopLeftCell As String = "A2"      ' change to match where your data are

    Dim Rng As Range                        ' data range
    Dim FirstRow As Long, FirstClm As Long
    Dim Data As Variant                     ' original data (2-D)
    Dim Arr As Variant                      ' data rearranged (1-D)
    Dim Tmp As Variant                      ' working variable
    Dim R As Long, R1 As Long               ' row counters
    Dim C As Long                           ' column counter
    Dim Count() As String                   ' match counter

    With Range(TopLeftCell)
        FirstRow = .Row
        FirstClm = .Column
    End With
    C = Cells(FirstRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(FirstRow, FirstClm), _
                    Cells(Rows.Count, FirstClm).End(xlUp).Offset(0, C - FirstClm))
    Data = Rng.Value

    ReDim Arr(1 To UBound(Data))
    For R = 1 To UBound(Data)
        ReDim Tmp(1 To UBound(Data, 2))
        For C = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Tmp(C) = Data(R, C)
        Next C
        Arr(R) = Tmp
    Next R

    ReDim Count(1 To UBound(Arr))
    For R = 1 To UBound(Arr) - 1
        For R1 = R + 1 To UBound(Arr)
            Tmp = 0
            For C = 1 To UBound(Arr(R))
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(Arr(R)(C), Arr(R1), 0)) Then
                    Tmp = Tmp + 1
                End If
            Next C
            If Tmp > 0 Then                 ' change to suit
                Tmp = Format(Tmp, "(0)") & ", "
                Count(R) = Count(R) & CStr(R1 + FirstRow - 1) & Tmp
                Count(R1) = Count(R1) & CStr(R + FirstRow - 1) & Tmp
            End If
        Next R1
    Next R

    For R = 1 To UBound(Count)
        If Len(Count(R)) Then Count(R) = Left(Count(R), Len(Count(R)) - 2)
    Next R
    ' set the output column here (2 columns right of the last data column)
    '   to avoid including this column in the evaluation
    '   it must be blank before a re-run
    Set Rng = Rng.Resize(, 1).Offset(0, UBound(Data, 2) + 1)
    Rng.Value = Application.Transpose(Count)
End Sub
```

The code will produce a result as shown below and write it to a blank column, right of the data. (Note that the code presumes that all data in the sheet are for evaluation, except those above or to the left of `TopLeftCell`).

[image]

Read *4(4)* (in the first row, which is row 2 of the sheet) to mean that there were 4 matches compared to row 4. In row 4 you will find the matching info, *2(4)* indicating that there were 4 matches with row 2. The result displays all matches except zero. This outcome is governed by this line of code.

```
If Tmp > 0 Then                 ' change to suit
```

If you change it to *Tmp => 3* you could exclude the noise. Of course, the result could also be applied in a totally different way. However, simply coloring matching rows won't do. As you see, there are quite a few qualifying rows and applying color to all of them would hide the information now available, i.e. which rows match with which other rows.

Comment: Is there anyway to edit the code to skip over blank cells? Thanks again!!

Comment: Do you mean there might be blank cells in the data and you don't want them counted as "matches"?

Comment: Yes, is there a small change I can make to the code you provided? I wish I had originally mentioned this constraint. It some cases there can be a blank cell within the columns. This is something that I definitely failed to mention. Thank you so much for the help so far!